# Registering a carrier service shipping rate with shopify carrier shipping API

Tags: api, curl, shopify

I am trying to register a carrier shipping service with Shopify's API but not exactly sure where to place the API call to register the shipping service.  So far I have an APP and able to athenticate and install the app into a test store successfully but how does Shopify store make the call to initialize and register the service after installation?

The API documentation states making a curl call:

curl -X POST -d @carrier_service.json -H"Accept:application/json" -H"Content-Type:application/json" -H"X-Shopify-Access-Token:TOEKN" https://aztest-3.myshopify.com/admin/carrier_services

Where should I make this call from?

Comment: curl commands are sent from the terminal. This seems like a http POST command to me.

Answer (score 1):

you can make this call from any terminal window that's connected to the internet.

most people would use their own computer's.. I ran mine from heroku.

I faced the same dilemma when attempting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that when the App is installed, it saves the access token provided in the response from Shopify in the App's persistence layer. When that save is completed the App can then initiate a session with the shop. With a session a call can be made to setup the Carrier Shipping callback and the App is then ready to go. A rate request will hit the designated end point and it is then (at least partially) responsible for providing shipping rates.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should have some kind of framework that handles the OAuth flow, storing authentication data for later use (like the [Ruby](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app) or [Python](https://github.com/discolabs/django-shopify-auth) implementations, or your own). In this case, you would want to use the framework's method for sending requests to Shopify, and not send requests manually through `curl`. The `curl` requests in the documentation are for quick-example's sake, allowing you to try out the requests yourself easily.

If you insist on triggering these requests manually, I would highly suggest using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)- It's much more human-friendly than `curl` and has some great time-saving features.